# XML documents and & char?

Tags: xml, delphi, parsing, special-characters, delphi-7

I have a question for XML document special chars, I'm using & in on of the value of the item in XML and TXMLDoc Delphi parser is complaining about it.

I search for some XML parsing options but none of them concerning special chars,

any ideas?

Example:

```
    <Configuration>
      <Configuration_item>  
        <view_name value="some view & name"/>

....
```

Regards,
Mika

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `&amp;` to represent an ampersand. The reason you need to do this is because & is a special character in XML - specifically, the character used to indicate the start of an XML entity, which is used to specify characters in the content that would (ironically) otherwise be special/complex characters.

```
<view_name value="some view &amp; name"/>
```

Other common XML entities:

- " is `&quot;`
- < is `&lt;` (short for less-than)
- > is `&gt;` (short for greater-than)

For more info:

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html

Comment: wow man, that was quick, I was still editing post, and correct! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`&`, `<` and `>` are the special characters you'll want to watch out for, and within an attribute also `"`. `&` is kind of like the XML escape character.

They can be escaped thus:

- `&` => `&amp;`
- `<` => `&lt;`
- `>` => `&gt;`
- `"` => `&quot;`

(Actually, and oddly, you don't really need to escape `>` within an attribute, only `<`. Also, if you use `'` instead of `"` for your attribute delimiters, instead of having to escape `"` as `&quot;` you need to escape `'` as `&apos;`. See the [AttValue](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue) reference in the XML specification for details.)

Answer (score 2):

Dav and lavinio are right.

If you have a block of text with lots of special characters you might want to enclose it in [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp) instead.

Comment: NOTE: You can't use CDATA for attribute values, just for blocks of text between tags.